# Definite article + possessive case :"Stanford's online offering of course X" vs "The Stanford's online offering of course X"

Tags: grammaticality, definite-article, possessives

Which of the following is correct?

> Stanford's online offering of course X.

vs

> **The** Stanford's online offering of course X.

Can we use the definite article before possessive *'s*?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but a combination of an article "the" and a possessive form "Standford's" seems very wrong to me.  I might add "the online offering of course X by Stanford" to the list of possible alternatives.

Comment: If there were more than one courses (e.g. X and Y), we could also write: "The online offering**s** of X and Y by Stanford"? Or "the online offering of X and Y by Stanford"?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really tell the difference

Comment: Related http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/58749/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would say

> Stanford's online offering of course X.

since you never refer to Stanford as "The Stanford". Or just

> Stanford's online course X.

To answer the question in your comment, this would be correct:

> The online offerings of X and Y by Stanford.

since there is more than one offering. You also use "online courses" or "online courses of X and Y offered by Stanford".